# sort out dataframe where index meet certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
          name    pe      outstanding totals     totalAssets
code                                                                      
300533   abc     30.04      2500.00   10000.00     82066.80   
300532   def     31.27      2100.00    8400.00     77945.25   
603986   NiT      23.40      2500.00   10000.00     89517.36   
600187  ITG       0.00    145562.42  145562.42    393065.88   
000652  IGE      929.15    146567.31  147557.39   2969607.50
```

I want to sort out those rows whose first 3 chars of index isin(['000','300'])

which the result will be：

```
          name    pe      outstanding totals     totalAssets
code                                                                      
300533   abc     30.04      2500.00   10000.00     82066.80   
300532   def     31.27      2100.00    8400.00     77945.25     
000652  IGE      929.15    146567.31  147557.39   2969607.50
```

thanks.

Comment: `df[df['code'].str.startswith('000') | df['code'].str.startswith('300')]` will get you a long way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str` to extract the first 3 characters from index:

```
df[df.index.str[:3].isin(['300', '000'])]

#       name       pe   outstanding    totals    totalAssets
#  code                 
#300533  abc    30.04       2500.00  10000.00       82066.80
#300532  def    31.27       2100.00   8400.00       77945.25
#000652  IGE   929.15     146567.31 147557.39     2969607.50
```